# How do I hyperlink an OpenLayers Icon?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have no prior javascript experience so bear with me. I create an Icon to place on my map like so:

```
var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('../Images/marker.png', size, offset);
```

Now I want to make that Icon link to somewhere. The documentation states that the constructor "Creates an icon, which is an image tag in a div" so how can I modify it to include a hyperlink?

**Update:**
I'm looking at using a popup with a hyperlink inside as a possible solution but I'd like to show the popup only when the user clicks on or hovers over the marker. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a popup and put a hyperlink inside it.
See [popup documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a possible solution. How can I make the popup visible only when the user hovers over or clicks on the marker? Since there will be multiple markers on the map I want to reduce the clutter.